# Operations in a block

Tags: node, transactions, protocol, internal-transactions

I have fetched the operations of a specific block and out of that have queris in one operation as shown below.

```
{
            "protocol": "PsddFKi32cMJ2qPjf43Qv5GDWLDPZb3T3bF6fLKiF5HtvHNU7aP",
            "chain_id": "NetXdQprcVkpaWU",
            "hash": "opCVF9q1WxpbtithUdvSADMG9WqyWtoAUUTRHieP3YWM5az1CKa",
            "branch": "BMK2P4H9REmzS5WPERfGrWa1oUANujyVpTmC3PQpmQTZ9qce6Eq",
            "contents": [
                {
                    "kind": "transaction",
                    "source": "tz1QRvrLoU3971B54WX4jemSZbyZiE2xff7B", <-- HERE
                    "fee": "12581",
                    "counter": "1136615",
                    "gas_limit": "122069",
                    "storage_limit": "0",
                    "amount": "0",** <-- HERE
                    "destination": "KT1CSKPf2jeLpMmrgKquN2bCjBTkAcAdRVDy", <-- HERE
                    "parameters": {
                        "prim": "Right",
                        "args": [
                            {
                                "prim": "Some",
                                "args": [
                                    {
                                        "prim": "Pair",
                                        "args": [
                                            {
                                                "string": "edsigtoQXvW766fq6BrGxKKVsnbKEFAD34jLxUF4U3f3GRonbewP8kx7rdYpbT78FQiXNybXugjHgPupVGNCqN42bwfzqcoPr8w"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                **"int": "398082603130"**
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "metadata": {
                        "balance_updates": [ <-- HERE
                            {
                                "kind": "contract",
                                "contract": "tz1QRvrLoU3971B54WX4jemSZbyZiE2xff7B",
                                "change": "-12581"
                            },
                            {
                                "kind": "freezer", <-- HERE
                                "category": "fees",
                                "delegate": "tz1VQnqCCqX4K5sP3FNkVSNKTdCAMJDd3E1n",
                                "level": 101,
                                "change": "12581"
                            }
                        ],
                        "operation_result": {
                            "status": "applied",
                            "storage": {
                                                            },
                            "consumed_gas": "111862",
                            "storage_size": "5152"
                        },
                        "internal_operation_results": [ <-- HERE
                            { 
                                "kind": "transaction",
                                "source": "KT1CSKPf2jeLpMmrgKquN2bCjBTkAcAdRVDy",
                                "nonce": 0,
                                "amount": "398082603130",
                                "destination": "KT1L3kB6eejPyXrAMRdtxYGF4DYzkJ7y38xn",
                                "parameters": {
                                    "prim": "Unit"
                                },
                                "result": {
                                    "status": "applied",
                                    "balance_updates": [ <-- HERE
                                        {
                                            "kind": "contract",
                                            "contract": "KT1CSKPf2jeLpMmrgKquN2bCjBTkAcAdRVDy",
                                            "change": "-398082603130"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "kind": "contract",
                                            "contract": "KT1L3kB6eejPyXrAMRdtxYGF4DYzkJ7y38xn",
                                            "change": "398082603130"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "consumed_gas": "10107"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ],
            "signature": "sigh97x6ZBruhxoGxsuy5CwvhsUifR84d4smLfwe96YexrRgTBefrhypCPeDeMW2izkPrVx1Wnff94GhYbnb6qvL1rJcCKec"
        }
```

- As per the above sample:

  - "source": `tz1QRvrLoU3971B54WX4jemSZbyZiE2xff7B`,
  - "destination": `KT1CSKPf2jeLpMmrgKquN2bCjBTkAcAdRVDy`

but again in "internal_operation_results" the source and destinations are different
"source": `KT1CSKPf2jeLpMmrgKquN2bCjBTkAcAdRVDy`,
"destination": `KT1L3kB6eejPyXrAMRdtxYGF4DYzkJ7y38xn`,

1. What is `internal_operation_results` ?
2. Does the transaction happen in this route `tz1QRvrLoU3971B54WX4jemSZbyZiE2xff7B -> KT1CSKPf2jeLpMmrgKquN2bCjBTkAcAdRVDy -> KT1L3kB6eejPyXrAMRdtxYGF4DYzkJ7y38xn` (Is this the process of delegation)
3. Is this `KT1CSKPf2jeLpMmrgKquN2bCjBTkAcAdRVDy` derived from  `tz1QRvrLoU3971B54WX4jemSZbyZiE2xff7B` ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Transactions can generate internal transactions, which are transactions to other contracts. See [here](http://tezos.gitlab.io/whitedoc/michelson.html#inter-transaction-semantics) for more info.
2. Yes, that is the order of transactions. However, I do not think this has anything to do with delegation.
3. In what sense of deriving? `KT1CSKPf2jeLpMmrgKquN2bCjBTkAcAdRVDy` is the address of another account, which may be related to `tz1QRvrLoU3971B54WX4jemSZbyZiE2xff7B` in some way (same owner?), but could also be totally unrelated. Addresses starting with KT1 are [originated accounts](http://tezos.gitlab.io/user/glossary.html#originated-account) (smart contracts), and those beginninng with tz are [implicit accounts](http://tezos.gitlab.io/user/glossary.html#implicit-account) (normal accounts).